# convert files inside into dataframe to another dataframe or RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a process that generates files every 5, 10 or 20 minutes. then another process lists the absolute path and saves them in a file every hour. 
the structure is as follows

```
logan@Everis-PC  ~/Datasets/dev/path > cat path1
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_D200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_S200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_V200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_D200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_S200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_V200_20190809.DAT
```

my code is as follows

```
val pathFile = "/home/logan/Datasets/dev/path"

sc.wholeTextFiles(pathFile).collect.foreach {
       hdfspartition =>

       val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(hdfspartition._2)).toDF
       a.show(false)

     }
```

but I get a dataframe with the data in a single row.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_D200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_S200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_V200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_D200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_S200_20190809.DAT
/home/logan/Datasets/novum_dev/in/TasPr_20190801_001828_V200_20190809.DAT
|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hi, I need to extract the contents of the files found in "pathFile". pathFile" has files with a list of more files. .DAT files (/../../novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_D200_20190809.DAT) have the data to analyze.
 I have tried to convert the first DF (wholeTextFiles) to a String Array and then to a String split by (,)

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(pathFile).collect.foreach {
   hdfspartition =>
  val fa = hdfspartition._2.split("\\r?\\n")   
   val fs = fa.mkString(",")    
    val cdr = sc.textFile(fs).map(line => line.split("|", -1))
    .map(x => Row.fromSeq(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use  `spark.read.format("text")`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate();   
val pathFile = "/home/logan/Datasets/dev/path"
val dataset = spark.read.format("text").load(pathFile)

dataset.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I need to extract the contents of the files found in "pathFile". pathFile" has files with a list of more files. .DAT files (/../../novum_dev/in/TasPo_20190801_001808_D200_20190809.DAT) have the data to analyze. I have tried to convert the first DF (wholeTextFiles) to a String Array and then to a String split by (,)

sc.wholeTextFiles(pathFile).collect.foreach {
   hdfspartition =>
  val fa = hdfspartition._2.split("\\r?\\n")   
   val fs = fa.mkString(",")    
    val cdr = sc.textFile(fs).map(line => line.split("|", -1))
    .map(x => Row.fromSeq(x))